# How to configure environment variables with vue-cli 3?

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, vue-cli-3

i try to use environment variables in vue-cli, but is not working, everytime says 'undefined' when use `console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URI)`. But `process.env.NODE_ENV` says 'development' as i defined in webpack.config.js.

I read the documentation of vue-cli 3 and put my .env.* files in the root project. like this:
[image]

**Webpack.config.js**

```
    module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    main: ['babel-polyfill', './App/index.js']
  },
  plugins:[
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ],
```

**.env.development**

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URI=http://localhost:64208/api/
```

**.env.production**

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URI=http://localhost:64208/api/
```

I use .NET Core with Vue. How to use the environment?

Comment: Well you did everything right! I just tried in my PC. You just have to restart your development server!

Comment: Vue cli 3 doesn't use `webpack.config.js` it uses `vue.config.js` - important distinction. You would set `--mode development` and `--mode production` in your `scripts` in `package.json` so the correct environment is loaded.

Answer (score 6):

it just happened to me, the solution is very simple. Just restart your development server.

```
ctrl + c
```

then

```
npm run serve
```

Comment: you could also check your `webpack.config.js` by running `vue inspect` in your terminal or `vue inspect > webpack.config.js` to add file in project directory.

Answer (score 2):

There might be different ways to achieve this, one easy way from command line would be:

```
npx vue-cli-service serve --mode production
```

Default to **development** if **mode** was not specified.

Comment: For whatever reason, inside a docker container I wasn't able to get the .env files to work via `npm run serve --mode=production` (I'm assuming it was a versioning issue somewhere), but this ended up getting the .env files to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename the file to `.env` only instead of `.env.production` or `.env.development`. it should work, if not, comment on the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the same problem that you had, but this happend in my case:

- I set up everything correct as you did (Not any .config.js file)
- I then stopped and startet the dev-server with npm run serve
- When I now refreshed the page, nothing changed in the console

Then I saw that the npm run serve command **had started the site on a different port!**. The old version was still running, but gave the old values. When I tried the new port the values where correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Vue CLI 3 with Core 2.2) I have to put the .env files under the Core webapp folder. It did not work if I have them in wwwroot or the Vue app folder.

[image]